# Add a em tag inside table header cell dynamically in Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a table in my code. The table headers are decide dynamically
The heder is for textbox column.

```
var thc = new TableHeaderCell { Text = "Iteration", CssClass = "iteration" }
```

I have to change the logic of how the label should be displayed to indicate the textbox entry is mandatory or not.

```
<em id="lblIterationMandatory" runat="server" class="mandatoryIndicator"
                                                style="display: none;">*</em>
```

I want to add a * star to the headercell if the text box value is mandatory whose css is defined mandatory Indicator class.
My output should be Iteration(black) *(red color,bold).

```
var thc= new TableHeaderCell { Text = @"Iteration <em id='Iteration' runat='server' class='mandatoryIndicator'                                                 style='display: none;'>*</em>", CssClass = "iteration" };
```

I tried this way. But * will not be dsiplayed.
Since both Iteration and * are different color I think i have to use a separte control for *.

Comment: Set the display of em to 'block'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set display of em to `none` change it to `block`

```
var thc= new TableHeaderCell { Text = @"Iteration <em id='Iteration' runat='server' class='mandatoryIndicator' style='display: block;'>*</em>", CssClass = "iteration" };
```

Comment: Yea ... Copy paste Mistake. Other place I am using similar logic . Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 2):

User `InnerHtml` instead of `Text`

```
var thc= new TableHeaderCell { InnerHtml= @"Iteration <em id='Iteration' runat='server' class='mandatoryIndicator'                                                 style='display: none;'>*</em>", CssClass = "iteration" };
```

also using `style='display: none;'` will hide any thing on the browser on which it is written.